# Function to Update Custom PSObject for DataGridView

Tags: winforms, powershell, datagridview

I'm currently working on a project where I'm wanting to show a status update when building virtual machines. I have a function that builds a list of names and "primes" the list. I'm then pushing this to a Sapien DataGridView.

The prime works fine. But I have a second function that I want to use to update that status. When I update the status it either removes all of the other entries in the Object or duplicates them. I also have some times I call this function it says it can't find the `$VMName` even though I see it in my verbose output.

```
function Set-Prime($NameArray) {
    $results = @()

    foreach ($Name in $namearray) {
        $OBJ = New-Object -TypeName PSObject
        $OBJ | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name VMName -Value "$Name"
        $OBJ | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Status -Value "Primed"
        $results += $OBJ

        Load-DataGridView $datagridview1 -Item $results
        $OBJ = $null
    }
}

function Update-DataGridView($VMName, $Status) {
    $Update = $results | where { $_.VMName -eq $VMName }
    Write-Host $Update
    $Update.Status = "$Status"
    [array]$results += $Update

    Load-DataGridView $datagridview1 -Item $results
}
```

EDIT:

```
Function Create-Names
{

    $namearray = @()
    [int]$i = $RangeS.Text
    [int]$e = $RangeE.Text
    $e++
    $Prefix = $tPrefix.Text
    do
    {
        $Suffix = "{0:000}" -f $i
        $namearray += $Prefix + $Suffix
        $i++
    }
    until ($i -eq $e)

    return $namearray
}
```

The `Update-DataGridView` function is done at various parts when I just call it to set the status.

Here is the Load-DataGridView.

```
function Load-DataGridView
{
    <#
    .SYNOPSIS
        This functions helps you load items into a DataGridView.

    .DESCRIPTION
        Use this function to dynamically load items into the DataGridView control.

    .PARAMETER  DataGridView
        The DataGridView control you want to add items to.

    .PARAMETER  Item
        The object or objects you wish to load into the DataGridView's items collection.

    .PARAMETER  DataMember
        Sets the name of the list or table in the data source for which the DataGridView is displaying data.

    #>
    Param (
        [ValidateNotNull()]
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView]$DataGridView,
        [ValidateNotNull()]
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        $Item,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
        [string]$DataMember
    )
    $DataGridView.SuspendLayout()
    $DataGridView.DataMember = $DataMember

    if ($Item -is [System.ComponentModel.IListSource]`
    -or $Item -is [System.ComponentModel.IBindingList] -or $Item -is [System.ComponentModel.IBindingListView] )
    {
        $DataGridView.DataSource = $Item
    }
    else
    {
        $array = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList

        if ($Item -is [System.Collections.IList])
        {
            $array.AddRange($Item)
        }
        else
        {   
            $array.Add($Item)   
        }
        $DataGridView.DataSource = $array
    }

    $DataGridView.ResumeLayout()
}
```

Comment: We need to know how the function is called to be able to accurately assist you. Plus we would need to know what `Load-DataGrid` is in order to tell why you are getting duplicates.

Comment: Edited post with the information requested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand, what you are essentially doing from the `Update-Datagridview` function is loading the `datagridview` with a whole new `datasource`.

The default behaviour is to redraw the entire `datagridview` and populate the data from the new `datasource`. Hence you would lose the data from the previous load.

`Load-Datagridview` seems like a custom function and since we do not have visibility into the inner workings of it, we wouldn't be able to comment to this behaviour. But I believe, somewhere inside, it would be doing something like this: `$datagridview.Datasource = $results`

So to preserve the existing data, this is what you do.

Step1: Convert your original `$results` table to a proper datatable before displaying. I believe Sapien forums can hook you up with that function. This will give `$results` a `Primarykey` property.

Step2: Assuming that you have a column whose data will remain constant through all the updates you make, you can make that particular column as a primary key. This will act as the reference point between all the updates you make. Do this after the `foreach` loop.

For Eg, Looks like your `VMName` column can serve this purpose. To set primary key:
`$results.primarykey = $results.Columns[0]` Where `Columns[0]` is the corresponding column index of `VMName` (I assumed it was your 1st column)

Step3: In your `update-datagridview` function, use the `merge()` method instead of Loading a new datasource.

For clarity, lets say that your updated result table is called `$NewResults`. Dont forget to convert this to a proper Datatable too.

Now all you have to do is merge your new datasource with the original datasource like below:
 `$results.merge($NewResults)` and your datagridview will have the new updates.

The `merge()` method also has additional flags. Perhaps you can find the documentation from Sapien's editor. Through some trial and error, I found that this was working for me.

```
$results.merge($NewResults, $false, 'add')
```

I don't know what the flags mean but it fixed my duplication issue.

NOTE: For merge to work, the data type of the values in `$NewResults` should match with the Data Type of `$Results`. I converted all values to `[string]` to keep it uncomplicated.

I know, awful way to get a seamless output.

Comment: This works. Thanks! The only issue I had was setting the primary key on the data-table. My merge works fine now without it.

Comment: Without the primary key, you run the risk of expanding your data table when the system finds mismatch between the data in existing datatable and new datatable. But i am glad that it works for you. SCORE!!!

Please consider selecting this as the answer.